# When should InverseBindingAdapter be used?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Why do I need `InverseBindingAdapter` in Android DataBinding, When should we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word `Inverse` is really saying everything you need to know, if you think of what DataBinding is actually doing.
If you enable DataBinding for your `Layout` you can perceive it as a pair of two things:

1. `View` (all `Views` included in `<layout></layout>`)
2. `Model` (all variables included in `<data></data>`)

*Regular DataBinding* makes sure that a change in the `Model` will have its effects in the `View`. It is invoked by `@{expression}`.

*Inverse DataBinding* makes sure that a change in the `View` will have its effects in the `Model`. It is invoked by `@={expression}` (the `=` char is essential here).

---

If you think what are the ways to make a change in the `View`, those can be:

- Changes in content (e.g. text in `TextView`)
- Changes of checked state (e.g. in `RadioGroup`)
- Changes in focus
- ...

Some of them are enabled by default and for others you will need to write a custom `InverseBindingAdapter`. More on that [here](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/).

---

*If you still need more information on that topic I suggest you watch [Google I/O 2016 presentation on Advanced DataBinding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAmMN7m3wLU).*

Comment: I would like to add that there is a [Documentation article](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/111/data-binding-library/6634/built-in-two-way-data-binding#t=201703150714422130506) about the built-in two-way DataBinding.