# Change ImageView color using two-way data binding

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to implement ImageView color changing with two-way data binding. I would like to have the same result as when I write ***android:src="#AAAAAA"***.

My ViewModel:

```
class TeamsViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {

    val teamOneName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("Team One")
    val teamOneColor: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

    val teamTwoName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("Team Two")
    val teamTwoColor: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

My XML:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/teamOneColorImageView"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@={viewModel.teamOneColor}" />
```

I don't know exactly how to implement color changing. I tried this:

```
object DataBindingAdapter {

    @JvmStatic
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:src")
    fun ImageView.getColor(): Int {
        val colorDrawable = this.drawable as ColorDrawable
        return colorDrawable.color
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    fun ImageView.setColorx(color: Int?) {
        val colorValue = color ?: Color.RED
        val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(colorValue)
        this.setImageDrawable(colorDrawable)
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

**Could not find event 'android:srcAttrChanged' on View type 'de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView'**

Next, I did a research and I tried this one:

```
object DataBindingAdapter {

    @JvmStatic
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:srcAttrChanged")
    fun ImageView.getColorx(): Int {
        val colorDrawable = this.drawable as ColorDrawable
        return colorDrawable.color
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("android:srcAttrChanged")
    fun ImageView.setColor(color: Int?) {
        val colorValue = color ?: Color.RED
        val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(colorValue)
        this.setImageDrawable(colorDrawable)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingConversion
    fun convertColorToDrawable(color: Int): ColorDrawable? {
        return if (color != 0) ColorDrawable(color) else null
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingConversion
    fun convertDrawableToColor(drawable: Drawable): Int {
        return (drawable as ColorDrawable).color
    }
}
```

Again, error:

**Cannot find a getter for  that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.Integer'. If a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.**

Do you have got any experience in something similar and would like to help me?

Comment: Why is there a "=" between "@” and "{" in android:src="@={viewModel.teamOneColor}"

Comment: @Traendy It's two-way databinding. I don't know if I can use it like with EditText, but I suppose I can. Change of LiveData value would affect ImageView src attribute and change of src would affect LiveData value.

Comment: Alright, I figured how to implement a custom two-way data binding. For interested, read this article:
https://medium.com/@henglim/diving-into-android-data-binding-inverse-data-binding-783e5e5a83d3

Comment: Why do you need two-way binding for that? Maybe I don't entirely understand your issue, but this doesn't seem to be a case for the two-way binding... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802610/when-should-inversebindingadapter-be-used/42803188#42803188